# Decode base64 iso-8859-1 string in javascript

Tags: javascript, base64, decode, iso-8859-1

How can I decode such a string in java script?
I know that by default utf-8 is used, hence all the decoders I tried (including btoa) tell me that the string is incorrectly encoded.

String:

> eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0NDM1NTczMzYsInVzZXJfbmFtZSI6IjJiNmNhOWRmLWM2MDMtNDc0NC1iMTVhLWRlZTUxNjdhMjdjYyIsImF1dGhvcml0aWVzIjpbIlJPTEVfVVNFUiJdLCJqdGkiOiI5NjE0MTc3NS1iNGI1LTRmYTMtYTMxYy00MDUxZDIxNGRlODMiLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiI2MDRhNjEyZC1jOWViLTQ1MjItODY2ZS1mOTE3ZDc2ZjI3MzAiLCJzY29wZSI6WyJBbGwiXX0.E-0Ouk6lW0tNJ_zEWDPfnTP7rGFfob5GrfxdR52KhTn2p1avNvaVrbSOWS_vEYl2xfHp9MEtDETzIKd8cWMXWdmAoc6F3ftNg2KVdK23ZHIrHr2Xj16FfV1nPwkcNtIdnaU_V4xQnCXgltaH91WYkmmAfZLPH9EOO9XovVeBJBIrTmaOc5FUSF3G859QxB1iaoN-DR14Pvm2oh6zTaDMJ8v9DRD2043yP3cZGwQItTjqf-Uz-FyAeG4IXMEdCgwQbZhV_fJdrNegKnJRh_ZJN2GHJgEEr-2b4Wg2DTtcY31XftNw-mbK0I3JYAg2DjxK9h_5XLmYJv19eqL6DFJm6w

Comment: Just out of curiosity - what gave you that string?

Comment: Cause `-`, `.` and `_` are not Base64 characters (known as Variants) and you're also missing one *padding character* `=` at the end  (at least with that length of characters.)

Comment: This is a JWT token obtained from oauth. It is not missing anything since it was successfully used to authenticate.